# Combine `to[short,*-]` with `|-` for orthogonal wiring

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I want to combine the perpendicular drawing of Tikz (`|-`) with the wire ending shapes of Circuitikz (`*-`) that is use inside the `to` operand.
I want to do something like the last line of code where the `|-` has no effect.

```
\begin{circuitikz}[x=10mm,y=10mm]
    \draw   (0,0) to[inline not] ++(2,0) coordinate (A) to[inline not] ++(2,0) coordinate (B) to[inline not] ++(2,0) coordinate (C) to[inline not] ++(2,0) coordinate (D);
    \tikzset{mux/.style={muxdemux, muxdemux def={Lh=6, Rh=4, NL=4, NB=2, NR=1}}}
    \draw (5,-4) node[mux,rotate=-90] (sel) {A};

    \draw (D) |- ($(D)!0.5!(sel.lpin 1)$) -| (sel.lpin 1);
    \draw (C) |- ($(C)!0.5!(sel.lpin 2)$) -| (sel.lpin 2);
    \draw (B) |- ($(B)!0.5!(sel.lpin 3)$) -| (sel.lpin 3);
    \draw (A) to[short,*-,|-] ($(A)!0.5!(sel.lpin 4)$) -| (sel.lpin 4);
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image: My output.]

Thank you

Comment: `to path={ |- (\tikztotarget)}`?

Comment: @user240002 maybe it would be possible but the `to path` macro of `circuitikz` is already a mess as it is, not sure if I want to do that... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't chain the `to` syntax with the `|-` because the syntax is `(coord) to[] (coord)` to draw an element. It will not work because `|-` is already a path element; it would be like saying `(coord) to[element] to[vertical and horizontal wire] (coord)` so Tikz does not know the intermediate point.

The easier solution here is to use this for your last line:

```
\draw (A)  node[circ]{} |- ($(A)!0.5!(sel.lpin 4)$) -| (sel.lpin 4);
```

Comment: I am on a tablet now, sorry if the answer is not so well organized...

Comment: No problem, it works fine to me, so Ill take it.
It's rare that you can't do both thing together in one step. Maybe I can build a macro that uses the calc library for more compact solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use (A |- B) for the point below or above A and left or right of B.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[x=10mm,y=10mm]
    \draw   (0,0) to[inline not] ++(2,0) coordinate (A) to[inline not] ++(2,0) coordinate (B) to[inline not] ++(2,0) coordinate (C) to[inline not] ++(2,0) coordinate (D);
    \tikzset{mux/.style={muxdemux, muxdemux def={Lh=6, Rh=4, NL=4, NB=2, NR=1}}}
    \draw (5,-4) node[mux,rotate=-90] (sel) {A};
    
    \coordinate (E) at ($(A)!0.5!(sel.lpin 4)$);% common north/south midpoint

    \draw (D) -- (D |- E) -| (sel.lpin 1);
    \draw (C) -- (C |- E) -| (sel.lpin 2);
    \draw (B) -- (B |- E) -| (sel.lpin 3);
    \draw (A) to[short,*-] (A |- E) -| (sel.lpin 4);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```