# Connection in `short` style with rectilinear edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'd like to use `circuitikz`'s `short` style on a rectilinear edge:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)}] \draw[-*] (0,0) |- (1,1);       \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)}] \draw (0,0) to[short,-*] (1,1); \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}] \draw[short,-*] (0,0) |- (1,1); \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On the straight edge, with `to[short,-*]` it works as expected; also, note that the connection mark is smaller than the non-`short` arrowhead on the first example. However, in the third one, combining `[short,-*]` with `|-` results in a missing connection marker:

[image]

How can I apply the second example's styling to the first example's layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the `-*` modifiers work only in a `to[]` command with a style that is a `circuitikz` object.

In your example, the first `\draw[-*]` is an arrow specification of Ti*k*Z,
created by the library `circuits.ee.IEC`, which is the internal (competing? ;-)) circuit library. In the manual you can find (around page 9):

[image]

...so basically, don't mix them.

The second is the correct usage; unfortunately, [it is impossible to mix `to` commands with the perpendicular coordinate system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593790/38080), so you have to use the node. Using only `circuitikz`, the correct code will be:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(2,0)}] \draw (0,0) to[short,-*] (1,1); \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
    \draw[short] (0,0) |- (1,1) node[circ]{}; \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly, you can define an arrow style that matches the poles of `circuitikz` --- but I do not know if it's so useful. Most of the time you use it in a `to[...]` or it is straightforward to apply the circ node.

You can even say `\newcommand\splat{node[circ]{}}` and then just use `\splat` in the path...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593790/2113 is exactly what I've been trying to search for, but search terms like "|- edge attributes" didn't turn up anything :/